# Should I update an android studio 4.0?

Tags: android-studio

When trying to update Android Studio in version 4.0 this warning message appears **"plugin incompatible with the new build found: Firebase Services"** I would like to know if I should update and if doing so would cause a type of error with the projects I am working with integrating firebase?

[image]

Comment: This is an English language site. Please ask your question in that language, or ask at [es.so] instead.

Comment: I have the same warning, I tried to update to new version 4.0 and everything worked as expected, nothing special happened, FCM still works without any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u want to remove this warning or if u have downloaded new update. All you have to do is Go to Settings > Plugins > Firebase Services , And uodate it. If update not available then uninstall it and reinstall it. It worked for me. And surely will worl for you. And make sure to update if u r using Firebase Services in your projects. Because it may create problem to you in using Firebase Services in new update [This is image describing where to find it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkA0s.png)